# Lining up Bootstrap responsive images

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, image-processing, responsive-design

I have three images that I'm trying to make a three image panel as the mast head image of the page.  Below is an example:

http://img0.etsystatic.com/016/0/5770030/il_340x270.467796830_hsfc.jpg

The outside images are 1:2 width to height ratio (but can be a little flexible) and the middle image's dimensions are more malleable.  Below is the code.

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= image_tag('Image1.jpg') %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= image_tag('Image2.jpg') %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= image_tag('Image3.jpg') %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now, image 2 isn't as long as images 1 and 3 and it feels like there is some sort of dimensions / ratios for the middle image that will allow it to scale to the same height as the outside images.  The ultimate goal is to have the three images be the same height regardless of the screen.

Am I crazy or is there some combination of image sizes that this should work with?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for Bootstrap Thumbnails http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#thumbnails . I played around with this on my own site. Bootstrap can rely on these classes for images and it uses data-src="holder.js".
    class="img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/100%x180"

after the holder.js/**your predefined size here***

this allows the image to be scaled up or down to the bounding area that Bootstrap has defined.

***UPDATED****

So I looked further and I still think that using this option will work.
Here is a link to a sample that I put together. I just made a override on the `class="thumbnail"` you can see this override right before the closing `</head>`

https://github.com/Gregory-Phillips/twitter-bootstrap-sandbox/blob/master/imageHeight.html

Comment: Do you think this will help though?  Because thumbnails are generally a uniform size, but my issue is that I have 2 photo resolutions that I want to try to get to line up vertically by using the image's resolution and column widths.

Comment: Well I think that could be a solution from what I can understand what you are looking to do. Take a quick look at my site. http://artoffitz.com/#drawing, If this is what you are trying to do? The Images are all different sizes natively and using the holder.js and using the column-3 the images stay within the same width and the length is adjusted to whatever the final proportion should be. Finally you could put padding on the two outer images using a % so they maintain responsive on screen size.

Comment: Close, but in the different columns it would adjust the width to make all the row's images the same height.

Comment: Hi Jeff I updated my answer with a second url to an example. Let me know if this is closer to what you might be looking for. I also realized that I had left some code that needs to be removed in my site. So thanks for letting me play around with your question... :) Also, it looks like you are using a MVC for your images. If so I would like to see your result. I have been messing around with Backbone and Angular and plan on updating my site with this type of templated injection for images.

Comment: Well this is interesting...I did this with your demo:

`<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <img class="thumbnail1" src="holder.js/400x800">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <img class="thumbnail1" src="holder.js/800x400">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
        <img class="thumbnail1" src="holder.js/400x800">
    </div>
</div>`

And it seems to work, but I must say I don't completely understand it the 3 pics are 79px tall and then kind of scaling correctly, but not totally right.

Comment: As for JS - I'm not using Backbone or Angular -- just RoR.  Also, for these experiments the placement images are kinda weird to work with, but if you don't want to include a JS file you can use: http://placehold.it/

Comment: I was applying the scaling to the images, it's not a perfect solution but controlling it finding a way to control the the child element; `<style type="text/css"> .thumbnail1 { width:100%; min-height: 10%; max-height: 20%;} </style>` I was wondering if you are injecting the images using templating you could just control the images using a control on the view. Though if you're trying to keep as much .js out of the site then using knowing how to use % is a good way. check out [Ethan Marcotte Article](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images) -fluid-images to have a good understanding.